# Possible to have a rounded/curved side, not corners?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to build something similar to the image below.

The container would be 100% width, the header would be fixed height, but the body height would be dynamic.

I was able to almost get what I want by doing the following to the "Body" div

```
border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0 / 15px 15px 0 0;
-moz-border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0 / 15px 15px 0 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0 / 15px 15px 0 0;
```

Theoretically, I would like to have the "Header" div be curved, and the body go underneath, but I dont think that's possible (the header will contain a filled image)

**EDIT**: forgot to mention. With the above code, and `margin-top:-15px` added to the bottom div, it did work in Firefox and IE, but not in Chrome and Safari. Maps and sliders still went over to the Header div and did not get cut off.

**EDIT 2** http://jsfiddle.net/ShKNu/4/

^ This is how I currently have it. As you can see, the map does not get cut off on the curve, and goes right into the header.

[image]

Comment: Put the header div _below_ the body div?

Comment: Have you tried a clearfix instead of overflow: hidden?

Comment: did you try z-index property ? body < div < header

Comment: _"I was able to almost get what I want by doing the following to the Body div"_ - could you produce a demo of that, and the case it fails in?

Comment: Here it is in Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ShKNu/ As you can see, it does work. But I need some content to go "underneath" the curve and when I add 3rd party content that contains `position:absolute`, it just goes over it.

Answer (score 2):

### You were headed in the right direction

Putting the curve on the "body" or `.main` section with `overflow: hidden` and a negative `margin-top` is a good way to go. To resolve your issue with 3rd party content that is `position: absolute`, you just need to make sure your `.main` has `position: relative`.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ShKNu/8/) with both positioned and non-positioned content inside `.main` (note: I tweaked the curve to be a bit more prominent for the demonstration).

It tests fine in IE9+, Chrome, and FF. Obviously, any 3rd party content that is being placed in the header or elsewhere outside of `.main` will not necessarily be hidden, but that should be expected. Yet even that can be worked around with proper positioning (`relative`) and z-indexing (`main` higher than `header`) set, as [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ShKNu/10/) shows.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `margin:-20px` or another measurement.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add. I did add `margin-top:-15px` to the bottom div, and it did work in Firefox and IE, but not Chrome and Safari

Comment: @LeeBurrows: Just because it ends with a question mark doesn't mean it's looking for clarification. Here, it's a suggestion, and removing the “could you” and the question mark makes it a perfectly valid albeit brief (if not correct) answer.